# Sharepoint Linkage to Access

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can i link an excel worksheet on Sharepoint into MS Access? So that any changes in that sheet will update my access database as well.

I have O365 Sharepoint with Access 2016.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways when you want to bring data from SharePoint into Access in either of two ways — by importing, or by linking.

There is an official article about how to import or link to data in an Excel workbook, which may be helpful to you:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-an-Excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958

You can also refer to this video:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-link-to-shared-data-0dadda2d-a795-4489-8098-c741879f4259